# Upgrade RAM 4GB to 12GB is that gonna boost my laptop

Tags: upgrade

I already upgraded HDD to SSD, and now want to upgrade RAM

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is an opinion based question and will be closed.  That being said, moving from 4 to 8+ GB of RAM *should* result in at least a  small but noticeable performance increase for most users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the memory requirement of applications which you want to use in your laptop.

if you use applications that require large memory to run like more than 3 gb of ram,then 4gb of ram won't be sufficient because other windows applications will also require Ram memory to run,and if your 4 gb of ram becomes fully used,then it will use your hard drive space as Ram and your laptop will become slower.In this case adding more Ram to laptop will give smooth performence.

if you only use general applications like ms office in your laptop then adding 12 gb of ram WON'T boost your laptop at all.

Thanks for asking.

Comment: thanks 
but i generally use my laptop to use Autodesk Softwares as Autocad, Robot Structural analysis and Adobe Softwares as Photoshop Illustrator After Effect and Android Emulator to play some game like Pubg mobile and Free fire and ... 
i wish this could help u to answer

Comment: the softwares which you use definitely require large memory to run smoothly.so adding more Ram will surely give you boost in performence.

Comment: okay thank you so much 
just one more question 
should i add specific 8gb RAM or it dose not matter ?

Comment: brand does not matter much but get the one which has correct specifications

Comment: most welcome brother

Comment: Id recommend jumping on the RAM.distributors website and doing a memory type check to get the correct RAM module/sku. In my experience RAM is the hardest component to buy correctly based on spec because there are so many variants. (Both Kingston and Crucial websites have this function) - and at least from NZ the wholesalers dont want to accept wrong purchases back for RAM.